# Logoff an RDP session to a Windows 2003 server restarts services

Tags: windows-server-2003, login, rdp

I have a weird issue that if I RDP into a Windows 2003 server, and then logoff (not reboot or restart) that the application services are being restarted.

I do use the `/admin` flag when I launch RDP if it matters.

**EDIT** - It seems it only happens with the /Admin flag.

I have no idea what is going on, but we have critical applications on this server, and I find I cannot logon to troubleshoot during they day because as soon as I logoff the application restarts.

Has anyone see something like this before?

Comment: Does the problem happen if you disconnect without logging off?

Comment: What are the services?

Comment: @mfinni - It's an java application server, it basically restarts the webapp.

Comment: @Joseph - No if I disconnect from RDP but leave my session active services are not restarted.

Answer (score 2):

/admin opens the 'Console Session". That is, it opens the local session as opposed to a RDP session. If your Java app is started with the same account, then as you log out it may be closing the associated processes for you Java app too.

Try creating a different admin account specifically to launch your service. Remember to specify the new account in your service start up.

Comment: The service is started as 'Local Ssytem', but is also set to start automatically.  I found an [article](http://servermanager.blogspot.com/2008/01/sm-automatically-shutsdown-on-signout.html) that deals with another Oracle JAS server that sounds like the same thing Im dealing with.  This may just be an Oracle bug.

Comment: That's not an oracle bug, it's java behavior. It's the -Xrs flag that's going to make it ignore termination signals from the OS.

Comment: @mfinni - But normally logging off a console shouldn't send termination signals right?

Comment: Clearly it is. "If the JVM is run as a service (for example, the servlet engine for a web server), it can receive CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT but should not initiate shutdown since the operating system will not actually terminate the process. To avoid possible interference such as this, the -Xrs command-line option has been added beginning with J2SE 1.3.1. When the -Xrs option is used on Sun's JVM, the JVM does not install a console control handler, implying that it does not watch for or process CTRL_C_EVENT, CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT, or CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT. "

Comment: From here : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html

Answer (score 0):

I've seen strange things with RDP. You might try disabling Remote Desktop rebooting and reenabling it to see if that does anything.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727977(WS.10).aspx